# Characterization of reparametrizations of a straight line?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $\alpha$ be a regular curve. How to show $\alpha$ is a reparametrization of a straight line $t\mapsto p+tq$ if and only if $\alpha^{''}(t)$ and $\alpha^{'}$ are collinear?

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show what happens when a''(t) and a'(t) are collinear?

Comment: Well, if $\alpha^{'}$ and $\alpha^{''}$ are collinear then $\alpha^{''}(t)=k\alpha^{'}(t)$ for some scalar $k$. Since I have to find $\alpha$ I thought I should solve the ode $\alpha^{''}(t)-k\alpha^{'}(t)=0$, right?

Comment: Yes! You could always say $\beta(t) = \alpha`(t)$ and then $\beta'(t) - k \beta(t) = 0$

Comment: Cool, that is easier to solve this equation. On the other hand, I guess it is a bit trivial, for if $\alpha$ is a reparametrization of a straight line then $\alpha^{''}(t)=0$ so $\alpha^{''}(t)=0\alpha^{'}(t)$, that is, $\alpha^{''}$ and $\alpha^{'}$ are collinear, right?

Comment: Yes. Just remember $\alpha$ and $\beta$ assumes value on $\mathbb{R}^n$ when solving your ODE

Comment: Ok, Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I'd read "collinear" as meaning "collinear for each $t$"; that is, the scalar $k$ is a function of $t$ (and there's no guarantee that $k$ is non-vanishing).

Comment: Well, I guess you're right. I'll change my solution adding the hypothesis $k(t)\neq 0$ for every $t$.

Comment: @user86418 In this case I'll have to solve the integral $\int e^{-\int k(t)\ dt}\ dt$ and I'm not finding a way to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}$Since $\alpha''(t)$ is proportional to $\alpha'(t)$ for each $t$ and $\alpha'$ is non-vanishing, there exists a differentiable function $k$ such that
$$
\alpha''(t) = k(t) \alpha'(t).
\tag{1}
$$

Let $q = \alpha'(0)$, and let $v$ be an arbitrary vector orthogonal to $q$.

By equation (1), the function
$$
f(t) = \Brak{\alpha'(t), v}
$$
satisfies
$$
f'(t) = \Brak{\alpha''(t), v} = k(t)\, f(t).
\tag{2}
$$

Any non-vanishing function $g(t) = e^{\int k(t)\, dt}$ (well-defined up to a non-zero multiplicative constant) also satisfies $g'(t) = k(t)\, g(t)$, so the quotient rule and equation (2) imply
$$
\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'(t) = 0,
$$
so that $f/g$ is constant. Since $f(0) = 0$, $f(t) = \Brak{\alpha'(t), v} = 0$ for all $t$.

Since $v$ was an arbitrary vector orthogonal to $q = \alpha'(0)$, $\alpha'(t)$ is proportional to $q = \alpha'(0)$ for all $t$: There exists a function $A$ such that $\alpha'(\xi) = A(\xi)q$ for all $\xi$. It follows that
$$
\alpha(t) = \alpha(0) + \int_{0}^{t} \alpha'(\xi)\, d\xi
= \alpha(0) + \alpha'(0) \int_{0}^{t} A(\xi)\, d\xi,
$$
which is a reparametrization of the line through $p = \alpha(0)$ with direction $q = \alpha'(0)$.